# Validaciones del tipo Request en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una duda y quiero saber si se puedo resolver con el metodo de validacion Request.

Tengo una tabla que se llama condando y otra que se llama localidad.

En laravel estoy creando una vista en donde una vez que se elija el condando
con un Select desplegable deberas escribir la localidad, la idea es asociar
las localidades con los condandos.

Ej: Dallas seria la localidad del condado de Texas en Estados Unidos.

Entonces  estoy trabajando con la creacion de la localidad,
y como ustedes saben en laravel existe la opcion de crear validaciones
usando el comando:

```
php artisan make:request nombredelrequest
```

he creado mis validaciones y hasta ahora las tengo asi:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'condado_id'=>'required',
        'nomb_localidad'=>'required'

    ]
}
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'condado_id.required'=>'Necesitamos que elija un condado',
        'nomb_localidad.required'=>'Necesitamos el nombre de la localidad'
    ];

}
```

Entonces hasta ahora estoy diciendole que es necesario tener la localidad y el condado,
pero yo quisiera de alguna manera usando este tipo de validacion que si intento registrar
otra vez la misma localidad en el mismo condado me diga que no es posible por que ya
existe. Puede darce el caso que una localidad tenga un nombre en un condado y exista en otro
condado una localidad con el mismo nombre eso puede ser posible, necesito es validar que si
ya existe el condando en la localidad no me deje registrar.

Answer (score 1):

agregaria la opcion de unique, en tu reglas

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'condado_id'=>'required',
        'nomb_localidad'=>'required:unique,nomb_localidad'//suponiendo que tu columna se llame nomb_localidad

    ]
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'condado_id.required'=>'Necesitamos que elija un condado',
        'nomb_localidad.required'=>'Necesitamos el nombre de la localidad',
        "nomb_localidad.unique" => "El campo localidad ya ha sido tomado.",
    ];

}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder... solo hay un problema si le agrego esa validacion como me dices estaria diciendo que solo en la tabla localidad existira esa sola localidad y en mi caso eso no es lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

La validación unique puedes pasarle los filtros que necesites. En tu caso el filtro del mismo condado_id

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'condado_id'=>'required',
        'nomb_localidad' => Rule::unique('condados')->where(function ($query) {
           return $query->where('condado_id', $condado); //Obtienes el condado de la request
        })
    ]
}
```